# Google Cloud Messaging server side

Tags: android, cloud, messaging

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging.  My internet provider uses dynamic ip addresses and when I try typing "http://my_ip_address:8080/gcm-demo/home" into the web browser as the Google tutorial says, the page will not open. Is there a way to set the server side up without having to have a static ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your server side code (GCM Server) at Google App Engine if you don't have your own server hardware/hosted solution.

Go to:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/

Comment: I will try that again.  I followed the basic tutorial once already and it asked for an ip.  I still got the same error when I entered my ip.  I might have missed a step.  Thanks.

Comment: Where did it ask for an ip? The GCM Server (the "servlets") is to be hosted either by Google App Engine, or any other publicly available server on the Internet, running any kind of JSP/Servlet container (like Tomcat or Jetty).

Comment: I followed the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html.  I just noticed that the tutorial just says App Engine for Java.  I may be getting that confused with Google App Engine.

Comment: Yes, I think so. If you don't have a web server compatible with Servlets API version 2.5, such as Tomcat 6 or Jetty, then you need to download *Java App Engine SDK* from https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java and then run it on your local machine. If you don't have a publicly available IP, your Android handset can only access your GCM server (the Java App Engine) while on WiFi/same network as your local PC.

Comment: You would also need Apache Ant to run/build *Java App Engine SDK* download it from http://ant.apache.org/. Then to start the App Engine; (cd to your sdk dir) cd \Android\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-appengine & %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -Dsdk.dir=C:/appengine/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0 runserver -Dserver.host=172.24.8.10

Comment: But then again, if you don't want to do any of the above, you can sign up for Google App Engine and upload your GCM server to the *Google App Engine* at https://appengine.google.com/